# what is the limit of tuples types in scala tupleN(n-parameters)

Tags: scala, tuples, scala-collections

How many different types of tuples are there in scala like tuple1, tuple2, tuple3
how many such tuples can we create and is there any limit to this?

Comment: [`22`](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/). You can have up to `Tuple22` because that is the highest tuple for which a corresponding library class exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The largest tuple you can take in Scala is Tuple22. 
If you want to have more then 22 then you can use tuple of tuple i.e.

```
Tupe22((Tuple22(1,2,3,4.....,22))(Tuple22(1,2,3,4,....,22)))
```

Like this 
You can also look into shapeless library if you want to have an arbitrary element tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The largest tuple type by default in Scala is `Tuple22`. At that size you're probably better off using a collection.

e.g. `Tuple22(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22)`